# lazy processpoolexecutor in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, generator

I have a large number of tasks that I want to execute and make the results available via a generator. However, using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` and `as_completed` will evaluate the results greedily and store them all in memory. Is there a way to block after a certain number of results are stored in the generator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea for this is to split what you want to process in chunks, I'll be using almost the same example than in the [`ProcessPoolExecutor` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor):

```
import concurrent.futures
import math
import itertools as it

PRIMES = [
    293,
    171,
    293,
    773,
    99,
    5419,
    293,
    171,
    293,
    773,
    99,
    5419,
    293,
    171,
    293,
    773,
    99,
    5419]


def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

def main_lazy():
    chunks = map(lambda x: it.islice(PRIMES, x, x+4), range(0, len(PRIMES), 4))
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = zip(PRIMES, 
                      it.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: executor.map(is_prime, x), 
                                                 chunks)))
        for number, prime in (next(results) for _ in range(4)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_lazy()
```

Notice the differences between `main` and `main_lazy`, let's explain this a bit:

Instead of having a list of all what we want to process I split it into chunks of size 4 (it's useful to use `itertools.islice`), the idea is that instead of **mapping** with the executor the whole list we will be mapping the chunks. Then just using python3 lazy `map` we can map that executor call lazily to each of the chunks. So, we know that `executor.map` is not lazy so that chunk will be evaluated immediately when we request it, but till we don't request the other chunks the `executor.map` for that chunks will not be called.
As you can see I'm only requesting the first 4 elements from the whole list of results, but since I also used `itertools.chain` it will just consume the ones from the first chunk, without calculating the rest of the iterable.

So, since you wanted to return a generator, it would be as easy as return the results from the `main_lazy` function, you can even abstract the chunk size (probably you would need a good function to get the propper chunks, but this is out of scope):

```
def main_lazy(chunk_size):
    chunks = map(lambda x: it.islice(PRIMES, x, x+chunk_size), range(0, len(PRIMES), chunk_size))
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = zip(PRIMES, 
                      it.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: executor.map(is_prime, x), 
                                                 chunks)))
        return results
```

Comment: The problem here (correct me if I'm wrong) is that the use of the parallel processes is not optimal. You'll only start processing the next chunk when all the processes from the previous chunk are done, so there'll be potentially a lot of idle time.

Comment: I don't know if I get you well @RafaelMartins, but in this case each process is computing each chunk "at the same time". Or at least you can compute a chunk for each spammed process in the pool

Comment: I may have confused myself with all the zip's and map's, but the first call to executor.map(is_prime, x) will immediately read the entire first chunk and assign each prime to a processor (for a total of 4 concurrent executions). Then the chain will return each of those 4 results before asking for more, triggering the executor.map for the second chunk, and so on. The thing is: the second chunk is only processed after the first chunk is completely done, so there might be a lot of idle time in-between. The ideal alternative would be to already start a new process after each prime is done.

Comment: @RafaelMartins, yeah, that would be the ideal. But in this case the question was to avoid too much memory dumping. So you only compute the chunk you need at that time iirc :)

Answer (score 0):

[I wrote a small gist](https://gist.github.com/CallumJHays/0841c5fdb7b2774d2a0b9b8233689761) that implements the required functionality without the performance penalty from using batches.

Usage is as follows:

```py
def work(inp: In) -> Out: ...

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as ex:
  # also works with ThreadPoolExecutor

  for out in lazy_executor_map(work_fn, inputs_iterable, ex):
      ...
```

And the implementation itself:

```py
from concurrent.futures import Executor, Future, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED
from typing import Callable, Iterable, Iterator, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import TypeVar

In = TypeVar("In")
Out = TypeVar("Out")

def lazy_executor_map(
    fn: Callable[[In], Out],
    it: Iterable[In],
    ex: Executor,
    # may want this to be equal to the n_threads/n_processes 
    n_concurrent: int = 6
) -> Iterator[Out]:
    
    queue: list[Future[Out]] = []
    in_progress: set[Future[Out]] = set()
    itr = iter(it)
    
    try:
        while True:

            for _ in range(n_concurrent - len(in_progress)):
                el = next(itr) # this line will raise StopIteration when finished
                # - which will get caught by the try: except: below
                fut = ex.submit(fn, el)
                queue.append(fut)
                in_progress.add(fut)

            _, in_progress = wait(in_progress, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
            
            # iterate over the queue, yielding outputs if available in the order they came in with
            while queue and queue[0].done():
                yield queue.pop(0).result()

    except StopIteration:
        wait(queue)
        for fut in queue:
            yield fut.result()
```

Haven't done a comparison with the batched version, but it seems to be performant.