# Memory Safe Permutations Generator with Increasing Length Value in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, permutation

Thanks to @rici in the comments for steering me in the right direction on this. I have discovered that `concurrent.futures.map()` and `concurrent.futures.execut()` utilize immediate processing of iterables, whereas Python's default `map()` function can lazily go through iterables, which is much more desirable when dealing with large `product` and `permutation` spaces. The `concurrent.futures` route uses up all RAM when it gets to combo's of 2 or more in the example code below.

What I'm looking to do now is implement what I have in the updated code below, with multithreading. What I'm looking to do is multithread Python's default `map()` function, pulling iterables from one common `product` generator. I've commented out the "working" multithreaded example for reference and to show what I was trying to accomplish.

I stumbled upon a potential fix in the `main_lazy` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135880/10018602), however I'm confused on how to implement that with my code's function that returns 2 values? The maps and zips and lambdas confuse me here, and I'm not sure how the chunk thing would work with the space I'm working with, but maybe it'll make sense to someone else.

For now, here is the single threaded version of the memory safe code that I'm trying to multithread now.

Note that I don't care about the math behind how many combinations this generates as it's irrelevant to my use case, so long as it keeps memory usage down. Here's the updated code.

To reproduce:

1. Download [VAmPI](https://github.com/erev0s/VAmPI) and start the server
2. Update the `BASE_URL` in the code below to match your server
3. Run this code

```
import concurrent.futures
from itertools import product, chain, islice
import requests, urllib


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                   Variables                                  #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
MAX_ENDPOINT_PERMUTATION_LENGTH = 3
MAX_WORKERS = 6
# BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/'
BASE_URL = 'http://172.16.1.82:5000//' # This should be the Vampi url of the 
                                       # server on your machine
if BASE_URL[-1] != "/":
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL + "/"


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                   Retrieve list of endpoints to product'ize                  #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
list_of_individual_api_endpoints = []
url = r"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yassineaboukir/8e12adefbd505ef704674ad6ad48743d/raw/3ea2b7175f2fcf8e6de835c72cb2b2048f73f847/List%2520of%2520API%2520endpoints%2520&%2520objects"
file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
for line in file:
    decoded_line = line.decode("utf-8").replace("\n","")
    list_of_individual_api_endpoints.append(decoded_line)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                 The multithreaded function we're going to use                #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
def ping_current_api_endpoint(endpoint):
    # Deconstruct a proper endpoint from the passed in tuple
    new_endpoint = ""
    for x in endpoint:
        new_endpoint += str(x) + "/"
    new_endpoint = new_endpoint[:-1]
    # Ping the endpoint to get a response code
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL + str(new_endpoint))
    status_code = response.status_code
    return status_code, new_endpoint


# # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# #                                 Main Function                                #
# # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# # MULTITHREADED ATTEMPT. EATS UP RAM WHEN GETTING TO DEPTH OF 2
# def main():
#     results_dict = {'endpoint':[], 'status_code': []}
#     # Start the threadpool
#     with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as executor:
#         # Try/Except for a keyboard interrupt. If this is not the correct implementation
#         # to stop a multithreaded pool, please demonstrate the correct way
#         try:
#             # Iterate from 1 to 3
#             for i in range(1, MAX_ENDPOINT_PERMUTATION_LENGTH+1):
#                 print("Checking endpoints with depth of", i)
#                 # Can change this from .map to .execute, tried them both
#                 future = executor.submit(ping_current_api_endpoint, product(list_of_individual_api_endpoints, repeat=i))
#                 status_code = future.result()[0]
#                 endpoint = future.result()[1]
#                 if str(status_code) != "404":
#                     results_dict['endpoint'].append(endpoint)
#                     results_dict['status_code'].append(status_code)
#                     print("Endpoint:", endpoint, ", Status Code:", status_code)
#         except KeyboardInterrupt:
#             print("Early stopping engaged...")
#             pass
#     # Print the results dict
#     print(results_dict)


# LAZY MAP FUNCTION, SINGLE THREADED, THAT I'D LIKE TO TURN INTO MULTI
def main_lazy():
    results_dict = {'endpoint':[], 'status_code': []}
    for i in range(1, MAX_ENDPOINT_PERMUTATION_LENGTH+1):
        print("Checking endpoints with depth of", i)
        results = map(ping_current_api_endpoint, (product(list_of_individual_api_endpoints, repeat=i)))
        for status_code, endpoint in results:
            # print(status_code, endpoint)
            if str(status_code) != "404":
                results_dict['endpoint'].append(endpoint)
                results_dict['status_code'].append(status_code)
                print("Endpoint:", endpoint, ", Status Code:", status_code)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                                 Start Program                                #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # main()
    main_lazy()
```

Comment: don't construct `dict` for `future`, instead just use generator! also the way you are using for `KeyboardInterrupt` is just hang the main thread.

Comment: This isn't your problem but I note that `(current_endpoint for current_endpoint in product(list_of_individual_api_endpoints, repeat=i))` is just a verbose (and probably inefficient) way of writing `product(list_of_individual_api_endpoints, repeat=i)`. They both generate the same values in the same order.

Comment: I guess that your problem, [as documented here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent#executor-objects) is that `concurrent.futures.Executor.map` differs from `map` in that "the *iterables* are collected immediately rather than lazily". I suppose it finds it convenient to do it that way so that the results appear in the same order as the iterator. I don't think the ordering matters to you but I don't see a way of communicating that to the library.

Comment: Thank you! I think you've steered me in the right direction. I see this post offers what I'm looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135348/lazy-processpoolexecutor-in-python
I also tried this repo, but I think it's outdated/for python 2, but it would have been awesome! 
https://github.com/natw/lazypool
I'll make the above solution work, and post an answer later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a solution. After the section of code that gets the endpoints list from github, I use the following:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                        Function to Ping API Endpoints                        #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Create Thread Safe Class for Generator and Worker Function
results_dict = {"endpoint": [], "status_code": []}
class LockedIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.iterator = iter(iterator)
    def __iter__(self): return self
    def __next__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.iterator.__next__()
            
def generator_function(repeat):
    for x in product(list_endpoint_words, repeat=repeat):
        yield x

def worker_function(current_gen_value):
    for endpoint in current_gen_value:
        # time.sleep(randint(0,2))
        if len(endpoint) > 1:
            for x in endpoint:
                new_endpoint = x + "/"
            new_endpoint = new_endpoint[:-1]
        else:
            new_endpoint = endpoint[0]
        response = requests.get(BASE_URL + str(new_endpoint))
        status_code = response.status_code
        if str(status_code) != "404":
            results_dict['endpoint'].append(endpoint)
            results_dict['status_code'].append(status_code)
            print("Endpoint:", endpoint, ", Status Code:", status_code)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
#                              Main Program Start                              #
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
start_time = time.time()

for repeat in range(1, MAX_ENDPOINT_PERMUTATION_LENGTH+1):

    thread_safe_generator = LockedIterator(generator_function(repeat))

    threads_list = []
    for _ in range(MAX_WORKERS):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_function, args=(thread_safe_generator,))
        # thread.daemon = True
        threads_list.append(thread)
    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads_list:
        thread.join()
    
results_df = DataFrame.from_dict(results_dict)
results_df = results_df.sort_values(by='status_code', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
results_df.to_csv("endpoint_results.csv", index=False)
print(results_df)
print("Elapsed time:", int((time.time() - start_time) / 60), "minutes." )
```

This creates a thread and memory safe generator and multiple threads for the workers. Now only thing missing is how to make CTRL + C work with this, but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import product
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed


words = ["I", "like", "to", "take", "my", "dogs", "for", "a",
         "walk", "every", "day", "after", "work"]


def gen():
    for i in product(words, repeat=3):
        yield i


def worker(rec_str):
    return rec_str


def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        fs = (executor.submit(worker, i) for i in gen())
        for i in as_completed(fs):
            print(i.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not address the memory issue I'm having. Allow me to update the original question for a more specific use case to show what I'm trying to accomplish as it seems I'm not explaining the question properly

Comment: @MattWilson why you not create a generator function for the list of words and iterate over it ? check updated answer.

Comment: I've tried that before, the same memory issue is present. Try to run the new code I've posted in the question above and you'll see what I'm talking about.